# Md-dialog popup box (angular-material) loads in as a new view (Yeoman)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

So I created a project with Yeoman (angular-fullstack, angular-material) and when I click on a div then the md-dialog box should show. Now what happens is that my page gets loaded twice and there is no pop-up visible although you do see the overlay (http://gyazo.com/c5e05ca2045c3ed9c32bb38d7bf67fc9). I am guessing that it sees my dialog1.tmpl.html as a totally new view. So how do I fix this issue?

Part of my code that is used to trigger the pop-up:

```
$scope.showPopUp = function(ev) {
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: DialogController,
                templateUrl: 'dialog1.tmpl.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                targetEvent: ev,
            })

            function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {

                if (editId) {
                    $http.get('/api/task/' + editId).success(function(data) {

                            console.log("data variabele uit de dialogController", data);

                            $scope.task_name = data.name;
                            $scope.task_project_id = data.project_id;
                            globalTask_Project = data.project_id;
                            $scope.task_location = data.location_id;
                            globalTask_location = data.location_id;
                            $scope.task_estimate_time = data.estimate_time;
                            $scope.task_project_client_name = data.project_client_name;
                            $scope.task_url = data.url;
                            $scope.task_resource_link = data.resource_link;
                            $scope.task_notes = data.task_notes;

                            $scope.closeDialog = function() {
                                var mainApp = angular.element(document.body).controller();
                                $mdDialog.hide();
                                editId = null;
                                globalTask_location = null;
                                globalTask_Project = null;
                            }

                        })
                        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            console.log("Error in retrieving data from server");
                        });
                } else {
                    $scope.closeDialog = function() {
                        var mainApp = angular.element(document.body).controller();
                        $mdDialog.hide();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try without "parent: angular.element(document.body)," ? Could you try to reproduce the bug in a plunker ?

Comment: @Okazari: hi i just tried it without  "parent: angular.element(document.body)," but is still loading twice. i will try to create a plunker but i am not sure its possible because the main index is using " <div ui-view=""></div>". not sure how to recreate the whole issue with the current way of working ...

Comment: you can try by forking this one http://plnkr.co/edit/A1zf8Haw2Haf4NJy7NEy?p=preview it also use ui-router and may help you to reproduce.

Comment: @Okazari: http://plnkr.co/edit/JZO9WZtXElOjPuSssxIN?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/NreRvnUhv55mHnZvxrg9?p=preview i resolved the crashing app. You need to add your $state definition now.

Comment: never mind i found the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue was that i had to se the route of my templateUrl correct so instead of templateUrl: 'dialog1.tmpl.html' it had to be templateUrl: 'app/calendar/month/dialog1.tmpl.html'